# How can I show vertical indentations markers with Emacs?

Tags: emacs, packages, indentation, indent

I'm looking for an Emacs package or configuration that makes it possible to mark indentations with vertical lines, like those shown in the following screenshot of Sublime Text:

[image: Sublime Text 2]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightIndentation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459159/671013) could be an answer to your question.

Installation is easy. Invoke `git clone git@github.com:antonj/Highlight-Indentation-for-Emacs.git .` in, say, `~/.emacs.d/highlight-indents` and add

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/packages/highlight-indents/")
(require 'highlight-indentation)
```

to your `.emacs`. Then, when visiting a file you can `M-x highlight-indentation-mode RET` to enable the minor mode.

Comment: PERFECT. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm.. `indent-guide` highlights whole column and I'm seeking for a thin vertical lines like on screenshot in question. There is `indent-hint` by ran9er mentioned on wiki page, but it is not works out-of-box. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `highlight-indent-guides-mode` and add it as a hook to `prog-mode`, so that it gets loaded automatically.

In Spacemacs, I did it by first installing it with `M-x package-install` or adding it as a user-defined package in `.spacemacs`, then `M-x customize-group`, `prog-mode`, `prog-mode` hooks, "ins", enter `highlight-indent-guides-mode`.

You can configure it via `M-x customize-group` `highlight-indent-guides` and change the indent character, coloring, etc.

So far, it works wonders and renders quickly.

Comment: Relevant git repository: https://github.com/DarthFennec/highlight-indent-guides

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to look at [indent-guide](https://github.com/zk-phi/indent-guide) mode. It gives indentation of code blocks dynamically when we move the cursor. Moreover, it is easy to set up your favorite indent characters like `:` and `|` as well as the background color of intentions.

Comment: I've briefly looked at `indent-guide` sources and README and found no way to set up indentation character, how can I do that?

Comment: @Geradlus_RU Here are my Emacs configure:.`(require 'indent-guide)
(set-face-background 'indent-guide-face "gray")
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'indent-guide-mode)
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook 'indent-guide-mode)
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'indent-guide-mode)`

Comment: Oh, I just realized that `indent-guide` is another package different from `highlight-indentation`.  Thank you, the former is what I have looked for!